# From a snapshot of the moment two waves of equal length overlap can it be discovered what the waves will split up to?

Tags: waves

What information does the snapshot need to be of? That is to say, what information holds the detail of the two waves?

Edit: I purposely left this question general because I want to know about superposition itself, without reference to the medium the waves are in, or even if it makes sense to isolate superposition from medium.

I wanted to not be too restrictive so as to hopefully not rule out a better way to ask the question if there is one.

Comment: Yes, if you know for example that the original waves are sinusoidal, you can use a fourier transform to find the frequencies of the original waves (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Fourier_series). Is this what you mean?

Comment: I was actually thinking all you know about the waves is from the given snapshot @CuriousHegemon

Comment: I think you should give more information and clarify your points in your post. And from the snapshot you should be able to find its curve and do a fourier series of it. Do you mean the time evolution of the wave? That you can't solve for.

Comment: I was trying to leave it general because superposition seems to be a distinguishing property of waves, regardless of their medium, but I think you are right and will add more to the question. when you say "can't solve for" do you mean there is detail that determines how the waves evolve but there are limitations on computing power? @CuriousHegemon

Answer (score 0):

No.

Consider these left and right going waves.

$$y = sin(kx-\omega t) + sin(kx + \omega t)$$

and this wave

$$y = 2 sin(kx - \omega t)$$

At $t=0$ they look the same.

In general, to solve problems about where something will be next, you need two pieces of information. For example, where it is now and the direction and speed it is headed. Or sometimes you can use where it was a while ago and where it is now.

Comment: is this due to incomplete theory, or is the information destroyed and recreated in the interference? or am i thinking about this all wrong?